# On lozenge diagrams

Tags: diagrams

In the literature of sequence transformations, some algorithms are nicely represented as lozenge diagrams, e.g.

[image: Wynn epsilon]

or in an extended form,

[image: Wynn table]

I could probably cheat and use `matrix`, `array` or some such construct, but might there be a better way to render these in LaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) to draw such diagrams. Here's a small example drawing your diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em] {%
      & \varepsilon_k^{(n)}   &  \\
  \varepsilon_{k-1}^{(n+1)} & &  \varepsilon_{k+1}^{(n)} \\
      & \varepsilon_k^{(n+1)} &  \\ };
\path[-stealth] (m-2-1) edge (m-1-2) edge (m-3-2) ;
\path[stealth-] (m-2-3) edge (m-3-2) edge (m-1-2) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Alternative packages for such diagrams are [xy-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/xypic), [amscd](http://ctan.org/pkg/amscd) and [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/).

For more TikZ examples visit the [TikZ example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) or this [blog TikZ category](http://texblog.net/latex/graphics/pgf-tikz/).

For the extended diagram, a matrix would be sufficient. But you could use the TikZ `matrix of math nodes` feature as well as in the first example, thus you could benefit from all features of TikZ like arrows, labelling, positioning and many more.

Comment: Hmm... as I suspected, I would require a package for this. Is there really no native way to do these lozenges in TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: You won't get nice arrows.

Comment: What are your reasons not to use a package? I would understand if you don't have TikZ installed, but amscd and xy-pic should be available on many systems.

Comment: Stefan: Well not very deep reasons, admittedly: the computer where I do the typesetting isn't mine to modify. But maybe I can coax the owner into letting me install TikZ. :)

Comment: That's an important reason. Show him the TikZ example gallery http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ , what can be done with TikZ, it might convince him. ;-)

Comment: @Stefan -- `amscd` produces only vertical or horizontal arrows, not diagonal ones, so isn't suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first diagram you could use any package that is used for drawing commutative diagrams. I usually use [TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) (see also *[Commutative Diagramms using TikZ](http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf)*).

The second picture can be typeset like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand\epsilon\varepsilon
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{matrix}
    \epsilon_{-1}^{(0)} = 0 &                          &                    &                    & \\
                            & \epsilon_{0}^{(0)} = S_0 &                    &                    & \\
    \epsilon_{-1}^{(1)} = 0 &                          & \epsilon_{1}^{(0)} &                    & \\
                            & \epsilon_{0}^{(1)} = S_1 &                    & \epsilon_{2}^{(0)} & \\
    \epsilon_{-1}^{(2)} = 0 &                          & \epsilon_{1}^{(1)} &                    & \ddots \\
    \vdots                  & \epsilon_{0}^{(2)} = S_2 &                    & \epsilon_{2}^{(1)} & \\
    \vdots                  & \vdots                   & \epsilon_{1}^{(1)} &                    & \ddots \\
    \vdots                  & \vdots                   & \vdots             & \epsilon_{2}^{(2)} & \\
    \vdots                  & \vdots                   & \vdots             & \vdots             & \ddots \\
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Caramdir (I'll reply here in your answer): Well if I don't need the arrows, like in the extended diagram, what would be the proper way of using `matrix` (or any of the other similar commands)?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Stefan, `TikZ` would be the best way to go:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,scopes}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,-0.5cm)},y={(0cm,-1cm)}]
    \foreach \x in {-1,...,3}
    {   \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
        {   \ifthenelse{\x=-1}{\xdef\more{=0}}{\ifthenelse{\x=0}{\xdef\more{=S_\y}}{\xdef\more{}}}
            \node[right] at (\x,\y) {$\epsilon_{\x}^{(\y)}\more$};
            \ifthenelse{\x=3}{\draw[dotted] (\x+0.5,\y) -- (\x+1,\y);}{}
            \ifthenelse{\y=3}{\draw[dotted] (\x+0.2,\y+0.5) -- (\x+0.2,6-\x/2);}{}
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(2cm,-1cm)},y={(0cm,-2cm)}]
    \node (l) at (0,0) {$\epsilon^{n+1}_{k-1}$};
    \node (b) at (2,0) {$\epsilon^{n+1}_{k-1}$};
    \node (t) at (2,-2) {$\epsilon^{n+1}_{k-1}$};
    \node (r) at (4,-2) {$\epsilon^{n+1}_{k-1}$};
    \draw[-latex] (l.20) -- (t.200);
    \draw[-latex] (l.340) -- (b.160);
    \draw[-latex] (t.340) -- (r.160);
    \draw[-latex] (b.20) -- (r.200);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]