# Using LaTeX to render hypergeometric function notation

Tags: math-mode

I decided to look if the solution [Caramdir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir) gave in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2098) would work as well for my attempts to use a new notation for hypergeometric functions. However, trying

```
{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}a& &b& &c\\&d& &e&\end{matrix}\middle;z\right)
```

resulted in the arguments before the semicolon being too widely spaced. I could of course just give up on the "staggered array notation" and align by columns what can be aligned by columns, or just use a two row, one column `matrix` and then use commas as delimiters, but I kind of like to see how to do a staggered array in LaTeX, and reserve `matrix` for the case of the number of parameters in both rows being equal.

So, how does one do a tighter looking (but still nicely spaced) staggered array?

Comment: I am not sure a staggered array is a way to go here, what if you need to do something like `{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}a-b+1& &b+a-1& &c+d-1\\&d-a+1& &e+d-b-1&\end{matrix}\middle;z\right)`, even if you make the the array tighter, there will still be a lot of space left.  How about something like this: `{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}a\quad b\quad c\\d\quad e\end{matrix}\middle;z\right)`?

Comment: That doesn't compile for me because ; isn't a math delimiter.

Comment: I've seen it with both semicolons and bars delimiting the argument from the parameters. I guess any of the two would work for me.

Comment: To get prepended subscripts, you may also consider using the `tensor` package, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334/non-kludgey-left-subscripts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
{}_3 F_2\left(\begin{matrix}a& &b& &c\\&d&
&e&\end{matrix};z\right)
```

That tightens up the spacing quite a bit. I made a hypergeometric macro previously, but it doesn't support the `;z`, unfortunately.

```
\newcommand*\pFq[2]{{}_{#1}F_{#2}\genfrac[]{0pt}{}}
```

Then you use `\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}`. (Or replace the commas with any other sort of spacing you want.) I was fairly happy with that.

Edit: Actually, how about something like this?

```
\newcommand*\pFqskip{8mu}
\catcode`,\active
\newcommand*\pFq{\begingroup
        \catcode`\,\active
        \def ,{\mskip\pFqskip\relax}%
        \dopFq
}
\catcode`\,12
\def\dopFq#1#2#3#4#5{%
        {}_{#1}F_{#2}\biggl[\genfrac..{0pt}{}{#3}{#4};#5\biggr]%
        \endgroup
}
```

Change `\pFqskip` to whatever spacing you want between the elements. You use it like

```
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
```

Comment: wow, I guess I'll swing with your macro instead. Thanks a lot! I guess with a little tinkering I could get it to render the Meijer G function and other multivariate hypergeometrics as well!

Comment: Hmm, wait... I see you use \Bigl and \Bigr here; I'm still confused when to use these instead of \left and \right. Mind explaining why?

Comment: It was a mistake. It should be `\biggl` and `\biggr`. I'll edit my answer. But the reason was that I wanted it to behave the same way `\binom` does. I find that most of the time `\left` and `\right` produce brackets that are too large. Most of the time, `\bigX`, `\BigX`, `\biggX`, `\BiggX` suffice.

Comment: A more efficient definition of `\pFq` appears [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47055/catcode-as-used-in-defining-hypergeometric-function)

Answer (score 10):

#### Update, with more features

The optional argument to `\pFq` is a set of key-value settings, but the settings can also be specified globally with `\hypergeometricsetup`.

One can set the `symbol` (default F), the `fences` (default brackets), the `separator` between parameters (default nothing), the `skip` between parameters (in mu units, default 8) and the `divider` (default a `semicolon`, but it can be `bar`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pFq}{O{}mmmmm}
 {
  % #2 = left subscript, #3 = right subscript
  % #4 = top, #5 = bottom, #6 = right
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { hypergeometric } { #1 }
  \hypergeometric_print:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hypergeometricsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { hypergeometric } { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl
\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_right_tl

\keys_define:nn { hypergeometric }
 {
  symbol .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_symbol_tl,
  symbol .initial:n = F,
  separator .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_separator_tl,
  separator .initial:n = {},
  skip .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_skip_tl,
  skip .initial:n = 8,
  divider .choice:,
  divider/semicolon .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl { \;; },
  divider/bar .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl { \;\middle|\; },
  divider .initial:n = semicolon,
  fences .choice:,
  fences/brack .code:n = 
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_left_tl {[}
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_right_tl {]},
  fences/parens .code:n = 
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_left_tl {(}
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_right_tl {)},
  fences .initial:n = brack,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hypergeometric_print:nnnnn
 {
  % the main symbol
  {} \sb {#1} \l_hypergeometric_symbol_tl \sb { #2 }
  % the parameters
  \left\l_hypergeometric_left_tl
  \genfrac .. % no delimiters
           {0pt} % no line
           {} % default style
           { \__hypergeometric_process:n { #3 } } % numerator
           { \__hypergeometric_process:n { #4 } } % denominator
  \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl
  #5
  \right\l_hypergeometric_right_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hypergeometric_process:n
 {
  \clist_use:nn { #1 }
   {
    {\l_hypergeometric_separator_tl}
    \mspace { \l_hypergeometric_skip_tl mu }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\pFq[skip=4]{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\textstyle\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\]

\hypergeometricsetup{
  fences=parens,
  separator={,},
  divider=bar,
}

\[
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\pFq[skip=4]{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\textstyle\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\]

\[
\pFq{1}{1}{\nu+\frac{1}{2}}{2\nu+1}{2iz}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer

A modification of TH's answer that allows `\pFq` to be in the argument of other commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newmuskip\pFqmuskip

\newcommand*\pFq[6][8]{%
  \begingroup % only local assignments
  \pFqmuskip=#1mu\relax
  % make the comma math active
  \mathcode`\,=\string"8000
  % and define it to be \pFqcomma
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\pFqcomma
  % typeset the formula
  {}_{#2}F_{#3}{\left[\genfrac..{0pt}{}{#4}{#5};#6\right]}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pFqcomma}{\mskip\pFqmuskip}

\begin{document}
\[
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\pFq[4]{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\textstyle\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\]
\end{document}
```

The trick is using math activation, rather than activation *tout court*. There's also an optional argument for changing the default spacing between the coefficients.

[image]

A modification for keeping the comma:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newmuskip\pFqmuskip

\newcommand*\pFq[6][8]{%
  \begingroup % only local assignments
  \pFqmuskip=#1mu\relax
  \mathchardef\normalcomma=\mathcode`,
  % make the comma math active
  \mathcode`\,=\string"8000
  % and define it to be \pFqcomma
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\pFqcomma
  % typeset the formula
  {}_{#2}F_{#3}{\left[\genfrac..{0pt}{}{#4}{#5};#6\right]}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\pFqcomma}{{\normalcomma}\mskip\pFqmuskip}

\begin{document}
\[
\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\pFq[4]{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\qquad
\textstyle\pFq{3}{2}{a,b,c}{d,e}{z}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us how to use comma separator for: a, b, c ?

Comment: @JanFilip Added the code.

Comment: Using update I got these errors:

! Bad mathchar (32768).
\\pFq ... \mathchardef \normalcomma =\mathcode `,
\mathcode `\,=\string "800...
l.368 \pFq{2}{1}{a,b}{c}{z}
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_n (b)_n z^n}{(c...
A mathchar number must be between 0 and 32767.
I changed this one to zero.

Comment: @JanFilip Sorry, I can't reproduce. It surely depends on some other code in your document. Please ask a new question with a minimal example of code reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica gave me the folowing when I asked it to give the TeXForm
of a generalized hypergeometric function

`_2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-c^2\right)`

and it seems to work. Simple and general !

Comment: Depending on what preceeds the expression, you might want to protect it with curly braces: `{_2F_2 \left(...\right)}`.

Answer (score 1):

Although it doesn't use "matrix" notation you can adapt from one of the `COOL` package solutions. Check out page 30 of the `COOL` package manual. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cool.

[image: coolhyper]

Answer (score -2):

If you ask Mathematica;

```
Hypergeometric2F1[2 a, b, c, d]
TeXForm[%]
```

then you get

```
 \, _2F_1(2 a,b;c;d)
```

and this works in Latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your answer to include some more details. Also note, that Mathematica was already used in another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125522/123129).