# Typing a specific type of matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I am looking to accomplish the following:

[image]

So far I have the following code but it's just not quite right

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\left(
 \begin{matrix}
  \nu+\tfrac{1}{2}\\
  2\nu+1\\
 \end{matrix}
\right\rvert\,2iz
\end{document}
```

Which compiles as

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! We usually skip greetings to focus on the question. Could you give us a minimum working example (minimum code that can be compiled)?

Comment: Welcome. // Latex is complex. Please give us more than just code fragments. Something that compiles after copy is nice.

Comment: I'm very new to this, fixed the code fragment so it compiles and added an image of the compilation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: While it's entirely ok to upvote answers immediately if you find them to be useful, site guidelines strongly recommend waiting several hours, and maybe even a day or two, before "accepting" any particular answer. That way, you don't discourage others from providing possibly even better answers.

Comment: You may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125531/4427

Comment: the solution given by @egreg in the linked post is so vastly superior that I am tempted to vote to close as a duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(updated the answer to address @yarchik's comment)

Here are two solutions. The first uses `\mleft(`, `\middle|`, and `\mright)`, where `\mleft` and `\mright` are macros provided by the [mleftright](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright?lang=en) package. The second uses `\Bigl(`, `\Bigm\vert`, and `\Bigr)`. Both solutions avoid creating an excessive amount of space to the left of the opening parenthesis -- a problem that arises when using `\left(` and `\right)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mleftright} % for \mleft and \mright macros
\begin{document}

\[
  {}_1F_1 
  \mleft( 
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \nu+\frac{1}{2} \\ 2\nu+1 
  \end{array} 
  \,\middle|\,
  2iz \mright)
  \qquad
  {}_1F_1 
  \Bigl( 
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \nu+0.5 \\ 2\nu+1 
  \end{array} 
  \Bigm\vert
  2iz \Bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico and @Willie Wong: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't `\middle|` be surrounded by `\;` instead of `\,` for correct spacing?

Comment: @SandyG - The screenshot the OP posted sure doesn't make it look like `\;` spacers were used.

Comment: `\middle` is defined in such a way that the horizontal spacing is taken care of automatically.  With `\vert` you'd have to space it explicitly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton did you mean the spacing for `\mid` and not `\middle`? AFAICT there is no extra spacing inserted for `\middle`; but `\mid` cannot be automatically sized.

Comment: @SandyG I wasn't aware there is such a thing as an officially "correct" spacing. I like `\,` in these cases because they look nice to me.

Comment: @WillieWong -- Yes, I guess I did.  I didn't check.  You are correct in all particulars.

Comment: Shouldn't space between the function name and parentheses be smaller? I believe it is not a product.

Comment: @yarchik - Good point! I'll update my answer and provide two ways to fix the spacing issue.

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfect place to use `amsmath`'s `\genfrac` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\hypergeom[3]{{}_1F_1\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\,\middle\vert\,#3\right)}

\begin{document}
\[ \hypergeom{\nu+\frac12}{2\nu+1}{2iz} \]
\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

In the definition above, we first have `\left( ... \,\middle\vert\, ... \right)`; this generates automatically resized `( | )` that shows up. The `\,` is used to add some spacing, the `\middle` applied to `\vert` makes the vertical line grow in the same way as the parentheses to accommodate the arguments.

The heavy lifting is done by the `\genfrac` command, which `amsmath` uses to create things like `\tfrac` and `\binom`. Here we just want to stack two terms one over another, and so we basically ignore the first four arguments. For more bout the `\genfrac` command, see the `amsmath` documentation.

An advantage of using `\genfrac` is that it follows automatically scaling when you use the command in in-line math versus in display math. See the image below:

[image]

The top line uses the `\hypergeom` macro defined above; the bottom line uses a `matrix` based incantation.
For things like the hypergeometric function, the down-sized expression (similar to how in-line fractions are smaller compared to display ones) is, in my opinion, more pleasing.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways. You can place the `|` character inside `mathrel` for proper spacing. Then adjust its size with `\Big` or `\bigg` if you want it bigger. Manually sizing the delimiters `(` and `)` will generally give you better results than using `\left(` and `\right)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\biggl(
 \begin{matrix}
  \nu+\tfrac{1}{2}\\
  2\nu+1\\
 \end{matrix}
\mathrel{\Big|} 2iz\biggr)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The middle vertical bar isn't as tall as the outer parentheses. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Mico: It was intentional, just to demonstrate that the sizes can be chosen differently if desired.