# How do I flush a piece of an equation to the right?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, formatting

I have the following expression

```
\begin{dmath}
    \int_0^1 y^{\frac{\dd-\ell}{2}-\dd_\p+s-1} (1-y)^{2\dd_\p-h+\ell-1}\\
    \pFq{2}{1}{s,s+j}{2s+j}{1-y}
    \pFq{2}{1}{-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p,-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p}{\dd-h+1}{y}
    \diff y\,.
\end{dmath}
```

This gives the following which looks very ugly.
[image]

Is there a way to flush the Hypergeometric functions a bit to the left? Thanks.

Comment: That wasn't working. And I meant flushing to the left in the title. Sorry, let me remove it.

Comment: `dmath` you are presumably defining with `breqn` that you don't mention. `breqn` changes almost everything about the math layout so any answer would be breqn-specific, and really you should say if you are using that. preferably by providing a small complete document that makes (just) the image shown.

Comment: dmath is for automatic breaking but you seem to have `\\ ` in your expression?

Comment: It is quite conventional to split a long equation (rather than two aligned equations) first line flush left second line flush right (amsmath `multline` does that for example) so your display looks Ok to me (and would not look better if you move the second line left) but as you have not provided usable code, hard to suggest any alternatives.

Comment: Please let us know how you've defined `\dd`, `\p`, `\pFq`, and `\diff`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first hypergeometric aligned with the integral symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125531/4427
\NewDocumentCommand{\pFq}{O{}mmmmm}
 {
  % #2 = left subscript, #3 = right subscript
  % #4 = top, #5 = bottom, #6 = right
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { hypergeometric } { #1 }
  \hypergeometric_print:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } { #6 }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hypergeometricsetup}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { hypergeometric } { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl
\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_left_tl
\tl_new:N \l_hypergeometric_right_tl

\keys_define:nn { hypergeometric }
 {
  symbol .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_symbol_tl,
  symbol .initial:n = F,
  separator .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_separator_tl,
  separator .initial:n = {},
  skip .tl_set:N = \l_hypergeometric_skip_tl,
  skip .initial:n = 8,
  divider .choice:,
  divider/semicolon .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl { \;; },
  divider/bar .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl { \;\middle|\; },
  divider .initial:n = semicolon,
  fences .choice:,
  fences/brack .code:n = 
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_left_tl {[}
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_right_tl {]},
  fences/parens .code:n = 
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_left_tl {(}
   \tl_set:Nn \l_hypergeometric_right_tl {)},
  fences .initial:n = brack,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hypergeometric_print:nnnnn
 {
  % the main symbol
  {} \sb {#1} \l_hypergeometric_symbol_tl \sb { #2 }
  % the parameters
  \left\l_hypergeometric_left_tl
  \genfrac .. % no delimiters
           {0pt} % no line
           {} % default style
           { \__hypergeometric_process:n { #3 } } % numerator
           { \__hypergeometric_process:n { #4 } } % denominator
  \l_hypergeometric_divider_tl
  #5
  \right\l_hypergeometric_right_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hypergeometric_process:n
 {
  \clist_use:nn { #1 }
   {
    {\l_hypergeometric_separator_tl}
    \mspace { \l_hypergeometric_skip_tl mu }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\hypergeometricsetup{
  fences=brack,
  divider=semicolon,
  separator={,},
}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}
\newcommand{\dd}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\p}{\phi}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\!
 \int_0^1 y^{\frac{\dd-\ell}{2}-\dd_\p+s-1} (1-y)^{2\dd_\p-h+\ell-1}\\
& \pFq{2}{1}{s,s+j}{2s+j}{1-y}
 \pFq{2}{1}{-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p,-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p}{\dd-h+1}{y}
 \diff y\,.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the number aligned with the bottom row, use the `tbtags` option to `amsmath`: with `\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}` you'd get

[image]

Alternatively, if you want such placement only for this display and not generally for `split`, you can use `aligned`:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&\!
 \int_0^1 y^{\frac{\dd-\ell}{2}-\dd_\p+s-1} (1-y)^{2\dd_\p-h+\ell-1}\\
& \pFq{2}{1}{s,s+j}{2s+j}{1-y}
 \pFq{2}{1}{-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p,-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p}{\dd-h+1}{y}
 \diff y\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Another possibility worth mentioning is to give a name to the complicated formula:

```
If we set
\[
 H(y)=
 \pFq{2}{1}{s,s+j}{2s+j}{1-y}
 \pFq{2}{1}{-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p,-h+\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}+\dd_\p}{\dd-h+1}{y},
\]
then we can consider
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^1 y^{\frac{\dd-\ell}{2}-\dd_\p+s-1} (1-y)^{2\dd_\p-h+\ell-1} H(y)\diff y,
\end{equation}
```

Fill in with the appropriate wording.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the first hypergeometric term on the first row?

[image]

Note that I've rewritten `\frac{\dd-\ell}{2}` and `\frac{\dd+\ell}{2}` as `(\dd-\ell)/2` and `(\dd+\ell)/2`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' env.

% Some macro definitions:
\providecommand\dd{\Delta}
\providecommand\p{\phi}
\providecommand\pFq[5]{{}_{#1}F_{#2} \Bigl[ 
   \begin{matrix} #3 \\ #4\end{matrix} \,;\, #5 \Bigr]}
\providecommand\diff{\,\mathrm{d}}
\providecommand\zzz{-h+(\dd+\ell)/2+\dd_\p}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
    \int_0^1 y^{(\dd-\ell)/2-\dd_\p+s-1}\, 
    (1-y)^{2\dd_\p-h+\ell-1}\,
    \pFq{2}{1}{s,\ s+j}{2s+j}{1-y} \\[\jot]
    \pFq{2}{1}{\zzz,\ \zzz}{\dd-h+1}{y}
    \diff y\,.
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```